# JavaScript losing "this" object reference with private/public properties

Tags: javascript, scope, window, this

I have the following error when running the page below:

"this.testpublic is not a function"

```
test = function() {
        var testprivate = function() {
                this.testpublic();
        }

        this.testpublic = function() {
                console.log('test');
        }

        testprivate();
}
new test();
```

Apparently when `testprivate` is called, "this" starts pointing to "window" instead of the object.

Shouldn't JavaScript preserve "this" context when within the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manipulate the context when calling testprivate.  You can use function.call to override the scope of the function.  Try this:

```
test = function() {
        var testprivate = function() {
                this.testpublic();
        }

        this.testpublic = function() {
                console.log('test');
        }

        testprivate.call(this);
}
new test();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `this` actually never was referring to the `test` object to begin with.  It was always referring to the nearest enclosing object -- which in this case is `window`.

```
test = function() {
        var testprivate = function(say) {
                console.log('test', say);
        }

        this.testpublic = function(say) {
                testprivate('test', say);
        }

        testprivate();
}
x = new test();
```

This works because, as I understand it, `this` is determined at *call* time -- and it is locked into the nearest "enclosing" object*, unless `call()` or `apply()` is used.

`*` There is probably a **much** better word for this, but I don't know it off the top of my head.  If someone knows, please enlighten us all :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't. The function merely defines scope.

When you call `foo.bar()` then `this` (inside `bar()`) is `foo`. Since there is no explicit `foo` in this case, it is `window` by default.

(`this` is handled differently when the `new` keyword is in play, but it isn't for that call)

Answer (score -2):

It is as Sean says: you aren't actually creating a new reference to an object (creating a *this* context), because you are simply calling the constructor - not utilizing the constructor to create a new object. If you use the **new** keyword, it works just peachy.

Since the scope of *test()* is *window* when you call it, any function called from within *test()* will execute in the *window* scope.

By using the **new** keyword, you are allocating a new object to memory - and creating a new scope.

For example, try this in firebug:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    this.memberVariable = "foo";
    console.log(this);
}
myFunction();
console.log(window.memberVariable);
var myObject = new myFunction();
console.log(myObject.memberVariable);
```

You will see this result:

```
Window stats
foo
Object { memberVariable="foo"}
foo
```

The Function base object has a method, *call()*, which as outlined by Craig, allows you to explicitly specify which scope the function should run in:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    this.memberVariable = "foo";
}
myFunction.call(myFunction);
console.log(myFunction); // "Function()"
console.log(myFunction.memberVariable); // "foo"
```

This is, however, not the preferred way of doing things, as you aren't actually creating a new object here, and typeof myFunction will still return "function" instead of "object" - when you really just wanted to create an object.