# "this" lost in javascript while referencing another object's function

Tags: javascript, window, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript losing “this” object reference with private/public properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322417/javascript-losing-this-object-reference-with-private-public-properties)

Why does the second alert shows the window object, and not the O (or even P) object?

```
window.name = "test window";

O = {
    name : 'object O',
    f : function() {
        alert(this.name); // 2nd alert
    }
}

P = {
    name : 'object P',
    f : function() {
        alert(this); // 1st alert
        var of = O.f;
        of();
    }
}

P.f();
```

In other words, how can a direct call to an object's function be in the context of the window? I guess it's a question of closure, but i have no idea where the switch happens.

Thank you.

Comment: Because you have detached `O.f` from `O`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var of = O.f;
of();
```

Your `this` gets mangled here, because `this` isn't really ever locked-in in JavaScript. It's very malleable and in your case you could do a few things to make it work better.

You can do any of these things to bind this properly:

```
var of = O.f.bind(this);
of();
```

or

```
var of = O.f
of.call(this);
```

or just

```
O.f.call(this);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Indeed there are solutions for binding a function to this, which i already use in the actual code, but my question was more of "what happens here? why does this becomes the window at this line?"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain scope of `O` then try this

```
window.name = "test window";

O = {
    name : 'object O',
    f : function() {
        alert(this.name); // 2nd alert
    }
}

P = {
    name : 'object P',
    f : function() {
        alert(this.name); // 1st alert
        var of = O.f;
        of(); // loses scope since this.of does not exist it calls using anonymous window scope
        of.call(O); // passes O as scope
        of.call(P); // passes P as scope

        this.of = O.f;
        this.of(); // maintains current P scope


    }
}

P.f();​
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QVSDA/

Comment: Ah ok! Right, so the answer is "it's called as an anonymous function. Still, i find it really weird that a call of a function inside an object can be considered as anonymous...